# Creating a dummy variable for specific calendar day

Tags: date, stata

In Stata, I want to generate an indicator for the 25th calendar day of the month, or the previous business day if that Calendar day falls on a weekend or holiday. I am using a business calendar in Stata that generates a missing value for non-business days.

What would be the most efficient script for this, rather than iteratively doing something like this:

```
gen d25 = d == 25
replace d25 = cond(d[_n+1]==25 & date[_n+1]==.,1,d25)

Etc...
```

Comment: I've changed what seemed to be illegal syntax. If that's not what you meant, please revert and fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```
sysuse sp500, clear
keep date

gen in_bcal=1
tsset date
tsfill
gen day25=cond(day(date)==25,1,0)
drop if missing(in_bcal) & day25==0 
sort date
replace day25=day25[_n+1] if missing(in_bcal[_n+1])
drop if missing(in_bcal)
drop in_bcal
```

This probably could be done in a more clever way.

Comment: There's a small glitch if the last date of the series coincides with the day being flagged. I've commented a bit more in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @Dimitriy's answer, I'd like to address two issues:

**1.** My interpretation of the original poster's question is that he is starting out with a *business calendar* in place. So the matter is about flagging an arbitrary day of a month (number) which can or cannot be present in the business calendar. If it is not present, then we flag the previous business day.

If this is the case, then we need a small addition to the original code, because `tsfill` will not work as expected if a business calendar is involved. (The `sp500` database `date` variable is not business calendar as `describe` will show.) An example is:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 19

gen bdate = _n
format bdate %tbsimple // format as "simple" business calendar

*----- tsfill -----

tsset bdate
tsfill

list
```

`tsfill` will not fill anything in this case; it will not fill in for non-business days. These days are scratched off the calendar, so there's nothing to fill in. We need:

```
gen rdate = dofb(bdate, "simple")
format rdate %td
```

which converts *business calendar* dates to *regular* dates. Then we can proceed with code like Dimitriy's, using the regular date variable `rdate`.

**2.** A second issue is that Dimitriy's code will result in a missing if the last observation of the series is precisely the day that we want to flag. This can be checked by looking for day 31 instead of 25. December 2001 will have a missing for day 31.

Below follows a complete example that addresses both issues, and hopefully, adds no error. Dimitriy, of course, takes credit for the general (correct) idea and any errors are my own.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 19

gen bdate = _n
format bdate %tbsimple // format as "simple" business calendar

list, sep(0)

*----- what you want -----

gen rdate = dofb(bdate, "simple") // from business to regular
format rdate %td

tsset rdate
tsfill

gen day6 = (day(rdate) == 6)

drop if missing(bdate) & !day6
replace day6 = 1 if missing(bdate[_n+1]) & day6[_n+1] == 1
drop if missing(bdate)

list, sep(0)
```